# Why the chart js annotation is not working properly?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

[image]

chart js annotation is not working this is my codes
this is the output
[image]

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

try this : (from : https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation )

```
{
    plugins: {
        annotation: {
            annotations: [{
                id: 'a-line-1',
                type: 'line',
                mode: 'horizontal',
                scaleID: 'y-axis-0',
                value: '25',
                borderColor: 'red',
                borderWidth: 2,
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

or check this working eg :

https://jsfiddle.net/caj89x6L/

Answer (score 0):

What this answer is missing is that you need to include the chart_annotations.js

Answer (score 0):

your annotation should be into option Bracket....